# Trigger Excel VBA, read and write to Excel from an Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, excel, plsql, vba

I have an Excel file stored at a file system location. I have the path in my Oracle procedure. I, however, can't find any resource online that would guide me in-

- Write data to a particular sheet in the Excel file
- Run a particular VBA function
- Read data from a particular sheet in the Excel file

Reinforce- I need to achieve all three of these through an Oracle procedure.

Any resources would be helpful.

**Note:** I am not trying to call an Oracle query or function through Excel. I am quite able to do that using ODBC. I am asking for something that's the exact opposite.

Comment: You could write a Java program which does all these operations. Then you can call the Java program from Oracle, see [Calling Java Methods in Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm). Or check this one [About Building External Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntqrf/about-building-external-procedures.html#GUID-DB15FD29-A121-4B3F-B422-1C8BF3FB696D)

Comment: This is a tricky - and highly unusual - requirement which demands some pretty low-level coding. Your starting point should be Anton Scheffer's excellent `as_xlsx` package; [find it here](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/). That package will handle your *write* requirement. It should be easy enough to extend it to handing the *read* requirement. Triggering *a VBA function* might be tough. It depends how you run the function in Excel: I mean, it is gonna be hard to simulate pressing `[F5]`

Answer (score 1):

#1 and #3 can be done using the [Alexandria PL/SQL Utils](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils) library. It's great and I use it for this sort of thing all the time.

#2 is never going to happen. You'd essentially have to write a VBA engine inside PL/SQL. A better question is, why is this a requirement? What are you trying to do?